# Conditional formatting on Multiple Rows based on cell value

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In my Google Form, I have custom formatting setup for my dropdown lists that will highlight the entire row based on the value chosen.

```
Custom formula is
=$B3="Highlight: 1 Row"
```

But how can I highlight multiple rows if I wanted to?

---

**Google Sheet Example:** [Highlight Multiple Rows](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IUj4aiz9iQ9tOQBiK-xJmhsNYr_Uo83AZxGJ8EOTIu8/edit#gid=0) 
**Screenshot Example:**

[image]

## UPDATE (01-26-2017)

The purpose of this "multi row" feature will be used inside a more robust spreadsheet that generates Google Forms from a Google Sheet. For this particular use case, there are many different "dropdowns" for the user to choose from that control where the user can type. This can quickly become hard to navigate the longer your sheet becomes. The best way it seems to handle this is through conditional formatting.

- [Highlight Multiple Rows](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IUj4aiz9iQ9tOQBiK-xJmhsNYr_Uo83AZxGJ8EOTIu8/edit#gid=0) *(Test Google Sheet)*
- [Create Form From Sheet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tockyjdnO_s) *(YouTube Tutorial)*
- [Create Form From Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ClPucMFkpp3sSegMDMOJV2Rh0csRqAMOlWPArqK7uKQ/edit#gid=334670914) *(Google Sheet)*
- [Create Form From Sheet](https://script.google.com/d/1nFjMguR8pRW7Kf8qVeRy_OSdpnq5BjX_IWX62r_Rj6b6ysRhX3oWeBde/edit?usp=sharing) *(Google Script)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this custom formula

```
=$B$3="Highlight: 2 Row"
```

Make sure the range you want this rule to apply to, is two rows long

e.g: B3:Z4

Now when "Highlight: 2 Row" is entered in B3 two rows should be highlighted.

UPDATE:

Below is a google script that should work

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sh, colors, rows, rowsBefore;
sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
colors = ["#fff2cc", "#fce5cd", "#d9ead3", "#cfe2f3"];
if (sh.getName() !== 'Example' || e.range.columnStart !== 2 || e.range.rowStart < 8 || typeof e.value == 'object') return;
rowsBefore = e.oldValue ? e.oldValue.replace(/\D/g, '') : 1;
rows = e.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4, rowsBefore, sh.getLastColumn()).setBackground("white")
sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4, rows, sh.getLastColumn()).setBackground(colors[rows - 1])
}
```

Change sheet name (and range) to suit. Note that this script is on a simple onEdit trigger: it will be fired when an edit is done in col B of the sheet 'Example'. Do not try to run the script by clicking the 'play' button in the script editor as it will return an error. See if that helps ?

Comment: That didn't work. It only makes the 4th cell highlighted

Comment: Here's a quick example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qxpF89di2ukxRPM1LE8K7sa8ATfFDXLaBoAzrderg8s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see that your example is working for the `absolute` reference, but whenever i go to type in further down the column `Highlight: 2 Rows`, it only highlights 1 cell. Is there a way to make it so that it's `relative` ?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not.

Comment: There has to be some way

Comment: I found this here.., is there a way to tweak this custom formula to work the way i'd need it to? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ScDqtZvhsmf2iByAuxHBu0-ESpX_TE5pdtBvAxOJ99E/edit#gid=1242454752

Comment: There should be possible with script. I'll have a look later on.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Oneezy: can you maybe share a copy of your spreadsheet so I can see the bigger picture (especially the dropdowns) because I imagine if the double row needs to be scripted, I might as well script the other options too ?

Comment: I've updated my question with more information. Here's the link you requested: [Highlight Multiple Rows](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IUj4aiz9iQ9tOQBiK-xJmhsNYr_Uo83AZxGJ8EOTIu8/edit#gid=0)

Comment: @Oneezy: I've update my answer with a google apps script. See if that works for you ?

Comment: Fantastic! This is **exactly** what I was looking for.