# Highlight multiple rows based on a single cell with blanks in between conditional formatting triggers?

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, conditional-formatting

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17CRAqPp_1FXQJAN7KtWMnLvmp54_jvBbrB1rES-yBbM/edit#gid=1220119768

The first sheet is an example of what I'd like, the second sheet is a fresh, un-colored sheet.

I'm trying to highlight 3 rows based on if the first cell located in the first row contains some value.

In this specific case, I have a workout routine type (upper body, lower body, etc) and the routine name on one line. It's rest information the next two lines. I want the rests to highlight with the routine name/routine type.

Since the routine type is rotated, as seen on the example sheet, the 2nd and 3rd cells after the type are effectively blank.

I think the closest solution may be this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868015/conditional-formatting-on-multiple-rows-based-on-cell-value), but this is an apps script and I'd prefer a conditional format. While I wait for an answer here, I will experiment with an OR statement, something like

```
OR($A1="Upper",$A1 - 1= "Upper", $A1 - 2 = "Upper").
```

Bonus: if possible, I would also like this rule to apply to just two rows but this is not necessary. If you look at the example sheet, "Static Holds" is just two lines.

Edit: This is close to what I want. Except, it only highlights the first cell in the row and not the entire row. Does anyone know how to reconfigure this to work across an entire row?

```
=IFS($A1="Upper",1,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))="Upper",1,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-2, COLUMN()))="Upper",1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try on range A1:F:

```
=(INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1), IF($A:$A<>"", {ROW(A:A), $A:$A}), 2, 1)))="upper")*($B1<>"")
```

---

```
=(INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1), IF($A:$A<>"", {ROW(A:A), $A:$A}), 2, 1)))="lower")*($B1<>"")
```

---

```
=(INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1), IF($A:$A<>"", {ROW(A:A), $A:$A}), 2, 1)))="back")*($B1<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: Works flawlessly, thank you. When you have time could you explain in layman's terms what the function does? I half understand it; the IF statement is throwing me off. Especially the array "{ROW(A:A), $A:$A}".

Comment: @SugarCereal191126 sure. in layman's terms cells A2, A3 & A4 are visually merged into one cell but in real only the top cell contains the value and A3 & A4 are empty. what this formula does is it checks each cell if its empty or not and IF it is empty it will get the non-empty value from above. IF its not empty it will just copy the actual value. see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/30prT.png

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with 3 rules offset by a row:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Player; do you know of any way to get the three conditionals as one formula? So, all the red formulas for Upper as one formula, all the green Backs as one formula, etc. I plan to use this for a more complex sheet and it'll be cumbersome to write/manage 3+ formulas per trigger.